# Centos 6.6 yum issues with NTP update

Tags: centos, yum

Hi I'm having an issue with yum, I seem to have broken dependencies? I have a general knowledge of Linux but I'm not sure how to fix this. Running CentOS 6.6.

Here's the output from yum:

```
yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.symnds.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ntpdate.x86_64 0:4.2.6p5-1.el6.centos will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: ntpdate = 4.2.6p5-1.el6.centos for package: ntp-4.2.6p5-1.el6.centos.x86_64
---> Package ntpdate.x86_64 0:4.2.6p5-2.el6.centos will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: ntp-4.2.6p5-1.el6.centos.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: ntpdate = 4.2.6p5-1.el6.centos
           Removing: ntpdate-4.2.6p5-1.el6.centos.x86_64 (@base)
               ntpdate = 4.2.6p5-1.el6.centos
           Updated By: ntpdate-4.2.6p5-2.el6.centos.x86_64 (updates)
               ntpdate = 4.2.6p5-2.el6.centos
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 2 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
ntp-4.2.6p5-2.el6.centos.x86_64 is a duplicate with ntp-4.2.6p5-1.el6.centos.x86_64
ntp-4.2.6p5-2.el6.centos.x86_64 has missing requires of ntpdate = ('0', '4.2.6p5', '2.el6.centos')
```

Running yum --skip-broken doesn't seem to do anything. I'm assuming this is important to resolve due to the NTP exploit that was recently found.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing this because a previous yum transaction, which was attempting to update ntp, was interrupted partway through. You're generally warned the next time you try to use yum, that you need to run `yum-complete-transaction`, but you may only be warned once. If you ignore the warning, you end up in this situation.

To resolve the problem, use the `package-cleanup` utility.

```
package-cleanup --dupes
```

shows duplicate packages (the problem here)

```
package-cleanup --cleandupes
```

removes the duplicates. You may want to `yum reinstall` the affected packages to be 100% sure.

```
package-cleanup --problems
```

will show you any other problems with the RPM database.

Comment: Thank you so much! Fixed it. Will mark as resolved as soon as I can.